# No Launcher Activity found

Tags: android-activity, android-manifest, adb

```
[2012-11-08 10:11:10 - BlueParking] Android Launch!
[2012-11-08 10:11:10 - BlueParking] adb is running normally.
[2012-11-08 10:11:10 - BlueParking] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-11-08 10:11:10 - BlueParking] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-11-08 10:11:10 - BlueParking] Performing sync
[2012-11-08 10:11:10 - BlueParking] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'S5830bf8abc43'
[2012-11-08 10:11:10 - BlueParking] Uploading BlueParking.apk onto device 'S5830bf8abc43'
[2012-11-08 10:11:11 - BlueParking] Installing BlueParking.apk...
[2012-11-08 10:11:15 - BlueParking] Success!
[2012-11-08 10:11:15 - BlueParking] \BlueParking\bin\BlueParking.apk installed on device
[2012-11-08 10:11:15 - BlueParking] Done!
```

I get this console output when I want to install my app. However, here's my Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blueparking.manager"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.BlueParkingApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androi.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.littlefluffytoys.littlefluffylocationlibrary.StartupBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.littlefluffytoys.littlefluffylocationlibrary.PassiveLocationChangedReceiver"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see, LoginActivity is the Launcher Activity. Can anybody tell me what's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Manifest.xml appears to be ok.

the name of the class is LoginActivity? extends Activity? do you load the layout correctly?

if you put here the code of LoginActivity we could see the fail

Comment: LoginActivity indeed extends Activity. However the problem is found before even trying to open LoginActivity: It does not found any Launcher activity, even though I'm pointing it's LoginActivity.

The best of all is it worked before.

Comment: <action android:name="androi.intent.action.MAIN" />

it must be                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

the letter d is missed in the word android

Comment: I'm officially in love with you, dude! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the Launcher Activity in your Manifest like that

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It looks like you already did that, so you can try in Android Studio in the Edit Configuration to select "Launch Options" - Default Activity.
I had this problem as well.

Check [here](http://www.onactivityresult.com) for more info about activities in android